# Is there a way to retrieve all metrics for a video separated by subscription status for Youtube analytics API?

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am trying to find all views for all the videos that I have that is separated by subscription status of my viewers. But I'm getting an error using these dimensions.

I am currently using a Wrapper library called Analytix and here's how I'm querying the results:

```
report = client.retrieve(
   dimensions=("video", "subscribedStatus"),
   metrics=("views"),
   start_date=dt.date(2000, 1, 1),
   end_date=dt.date(2022, 3, 31),
   include_historical_data=True,
   max_results=100,
   sort_options=["-views"])
```

Comment: *But I'm getting an error using these dimensions.* may you precise which error?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Error code from Analytix console says: unsupported dimension(s) for selected report type: subscribedStatus

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Author of analytix here. I'm a bit late to the party, but hopefully this should help.

The error "unsupported dimension(s) for selected report type" appears when two dimensions are incompatible. The YouTube Analytics API physically won't let you use those dimensions together.

What I believe you're trying to do isn't possible. You would need to make a separate request for every video (filtering by video ID and using subscribedStatus as the only dimension) and concatenate the report rows into one report.

If you wanna go down that route, you can use the Data API or [scrapetube](https://pypi.org/project/scrapetube/) to get all your video IDs. Note that you are limited to 720 requests per minute, and analytix doesn't manage ratelimits automatically.

It's an unfortunate flaw (likely design choice) with the Analytics API that I can't do anything about. Hope this helps though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to clarify, is the "720 request per minute" a limit from Youtube or from Scrapetube?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, didn't see this. That is a limit from the YouTube Analytics API -- scrapetube sets its own limits at 1 request per second, though you won't have to worry about that as scrapetube handles ratelimiting for you.